# Compiler not recognizing class existence, even after importing header

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

So when I'm typing the name of the class, `cue`, it shows up in XCode as a suggestion for what to write and when I'm importing the header the same thing happens (XCode suggests the header I'm importing as I type) so the file address is definitely right. Yet it gives me an error that the type I typed does not exist, or in methods it tells me that I need a type name.

Class interface:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "CueTableCell.h"
#import "CueList.h"

typedef enum {
    none,
    immediate,
    after,
    afterWait,
} CueType;

@interface Cue : NSObject

@property CueType cueType;
@property NSString* title;
@property float wait;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Cue* nextCue;
@property CueTableCell* cell;
@property CueList* list;

-(id) initWithTitle: (NSString*) title cueType: (CueType) type list: (CueList*) list cell: (CueTableCell*) cell wait: (float) wait thenCall: (Cue*) nextCue ;

-(void) fire; //Should not be async.
-(void) reset; //Pauses and resets everything
-(void) callNext;
-(void) selected;
-(void) select;

@end
```

CueTableCell file that will not recognize the Cue.h file:

```
    #import "Cue.h"
    @interface CueTableCell : UITableViewCell

    -(void) updateBarAt: (float) playHead;
    -(void) updateBarIncrease: (float) by;

    - (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title wait: (float) wait fadeOut: (float) fadeOut fadeIn: (float) fadeIn playFor: (float) playFor;

    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel* titleLabel;
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel* waitLabel;
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel* fadeInLabel;
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel* fadeOutLabel;
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel* playForLabel;

    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* title;
    @property (nonatomic) float wait;
    @property (nonatomic) float fadeIn;
    @property (nonatomic) float fadeOut;
    @property (nonatomic) float playFor;

    @property (nonatomic, weak) Cue* cue; # <---- Get an error that Cue is not a type

    @end

For some reason, the compiler recognizes Cue importing CueTableCell, but not the other way around. Cue is at the top of a class hierarchy, so other files clearly are able to import it. I've tried changing the group and file location of CueTableCell, and nothing helps.
```

Comment: Is that the complete header to `CueTableCell`?

Comment: did you `#import "Cue.h"` anywhere?

Comment: It looks like you have your imports backward. At the time `CueTableCell.h` is compiled (whether you import it directly, or via `Cue.h`), `Cue` hasn't been defined yet, so of course the compiler doesn't recognize it.

Comment: @abarnert, you're right but I suspect, more specifically, that he's actually got circular `#import`s. @MikeG, use forward `@class` declarations instead of `#import`s in headers.

Comment: @abarnert hadn't noticed that, but now that you mention it, it's actually that both reference each other. He needs to split the definitions. I can't remember the Objective C way of doing that so I'll leave it to somebody else to answer.

Comment: @KenThomases: The first one is pretty clearly the complete header, so I'm guessing the second one is as well, which means there's no circular imports going on. Which means he _could_ fix this with just a single forward declaration and not change anything else. That may not be the _right_ fix, but… that's too hard to explain in a comment, which is why I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#import` just does textual substitution. So, at the time the compiler tries to compile `CueTableCell`, `Cue` hasn't been defined yet.

If you just `#import "Cue.h"`, it does an `#import "CueTableCell.h"` before defining `Cue` anywhere. If you directly `#import "CueTableCell.h"` yourself, `Cue` isn't defined *anywhere*. Either way, you can't use it; the compiler has no idea that it's supposed to be the name of an ObjC type. (It could just as easily be all kinds of things—even a global-variable int.)

If you get rid of that `#import` at the top of `Cue.h`, and instead do a `#import "Cue.h"` in `CueTableCell.h`, that will solve this problem… but immediately create a new, equivalent one, because as soon as the compiler gets to `@property CueTableCell* cell;` it will complain that `CueTableCell` isn't a type.

This is what [forward declarations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) are for. Just add a `@class Cue;` to `CueTableCell.h`, and the compiler will know that `Cue` is an ObjC class (which is all it needs to know at this point).

You can probably also just add `@class CueTableCell;` to `Cue.h`, and remove the `#import "CueTableCell.h"` there, and likely the same for `CueList` as well. Of course the .m files will probably need to include all of the headers, but that's fine; they don't have to import each other, so there's no danger of circularity.

The only reason you really need to put a `#import "Foo.h"` into a header file `Bar.h` is if anyone who wants to use `Bar` will also need to use `Foo`, and couldn't be expected to know that and add a `#import "Foo.h"` into his .m file.